# How to resolve .net version conflicts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version, .net-standard

I have the following warning messages during build.

```
No way to resolve conflict between "System.ComponentModel.Annotations, 
Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and 
"System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Choosing 
"System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" arbitrarily.
```

We have around 70 C# projects (net framework 462, net core, net standard). Are there any automated tools to fix the version conflicts problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/configuring-assembly-binding-redirection

Comment: I have found nothing to this day to make it automated, and i continue to make it "by hand" every time a library is updated :(

Comment: The problem for me to configure manually is that I cannot find the where is the problem. For example, I search all the projects and couldn't find the System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.0.10.0 anywhere.

Comment: Can you share the image of your dependencies(.dll)?

Comment: You could generate a restore graph file through `msbuild /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /p:RestoreGraphOutputPath=graph.dg` (dev console) and look at which packages are used. I'm guessing there are also some projects where you reference `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` manually from the framework and not through NuGet so none of NuGet's resolving logic kicks in.

Comment: I found a tool that can be used to find all references in DLL. Here is the link. https://github.com/mikehadlow/AsmSpy

Comment: I now found that my C++/CLI uses version 4.0.10.0 references net framework 4.6.2 while a netStandard 1.5 C# project references version 4.1.0.0. Is there a way to change the version in C++/CLI project?